# Al realizar POST utilizando el método fetch el header Content-Type parece no tomarse en cuenta

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, http

Al intentar enviar una petición POST al servidor le asigno el header 'Content-Type': 'application/json', pero al recibirlo en el server no se muestra la información que envié, se muestra una estructura vacía {}, al revisar los headers del request noté que el Content-Type aparece como 'text/plain'.

¿Alguien sabe a que pueda deberse que no se tome en cuenta la información que envío en el header?

Tengo el siguiente método en mi front de React:

```
handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        mode: 'no-cors',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({email:'carlos@gmail.com'})
    };
    fetch('http://localhost:3001/users/validateUser',options).then(response =>{
        console.log(response);
    });
}
```

Al revisar la respuesta en mi servidor NodeJS/Express veo que se recibió el header 'content-type': 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8'

[image: Información de la consola del servidor]

El código de mi api es el siguiente:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.use(express.static('public'));
router.use(express.json({limit: '1mb'}));
router.use(require("body-parser").json());

router.get('/users', function(req, res) {
  res.render('users', { title: 'Users' });
});

router.post('/validateUser',(req,res)=>{
  console.log(req.headers);
  console.log(req.body);
  res.send(true);
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Carlos, si la respuesta aportada solucionó tu problema, la mehor forma de agradacerlo es votando positivo y aceptando la respuesta como válida. Te invito a leer lo que dice el [Centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) al respecto sobre lo que debemos hacer cuando alguien responde nuestra pregunta. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema parece ser muy simple, y si no me equivoco la linea que esta mal es:

```
JSON.stringify({email:'carlos@gmail.com'})
```

Ya que en:

```
'Content-Type': 'application/json'
```

Indicas que lo que envias es un JSON, pero al utilizar `JSON.stringify` conviertes el `json` en string, razon por la cual tus datos no llegan al servidor.

Te recomiendo enviar solo el `JSON`, asi:

```
body: {email:'carlos@gmail.com'}
```